# pip not installing cryptography

Tags: cryptography, pip

I am running pip on an Arduino Yun, which runs OpenWRT, a variant of Linux.

On this device, I already have multiple packages installed, such as crypto, pycrypto, pyOpenSSL, etc.

When I run `pip install cryptography`:

```
Collecting cryptography
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76895850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/cryptography/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x768950f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/cryptography/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x768951d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/cryptography/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76895650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/cryptography/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76895a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/cryptography/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cryptography (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cryptography
```

When I run `pip show cryptography`, it returns a blank.

When I run `pip show pip` (for comparison):

```
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: pip
Version: 8.1.2
...
```

When I run `pip search cryptography`:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76d48690>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /pypi
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76d3dc90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /pypi
^COperation cancelled by user
```

By contrast, I then tried a different package: `pip install crypto`:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): crypto in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): shellescape in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from crypto)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Naked in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from crypto)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Naked->crypto)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyyaml in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Naked->crypto)
```

Any idea what is going on here, and how I can successfully install cryptography?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that you have networking issues. This is not normal:

```
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x76895850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'
```